# Intuitive explanation of probability density and probability current

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability

I was given the wavefunction $\psi(x)= C e^{-x/a}e^{ibx}, 0< x < \infty$ and asked to compute $J$, the probability current and $d\rho/dt$, the change in the probability density with respect to time. That is fairly straightforward, using $d\rho/dt = -dJ/dx$, however I'm a bit confused as to why $d\rho/dt$ is nonzero. If $\Psi(x,t) = \psi(x) e^{i\omega t}$, shouldn't it follow that $\rho$ is time independent?

Also, it seems that if the wavefunction did not have the $e^{ibx}$ factor, then $d\rho/dt= 0$, so is there an intuitive explanation as to why this happens?

Additional details: I wasn't given the Hamiltonian or told anything about eigenstates. The question simply gave me the above wavefunction and asked to find the following:

1. the probability density $\rho(x)$,
2. The probability current $J(x)$ and
3. $\partial\rho/\partial t$.

Here are the values I found for the above:

1. $|C|^2 = \frac{4}{a^3}\implies \rho(x) = \frac{4}{a^3}x^2e^{-2x/a}$
2. $\Psi(x,t) = \psi(x)e^{-i\omega t}\implies J(x) = \frac{i\hbar}{2m}(\Psi\frac{\partial\Psi^*}{\partial x} - \Psi^*\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x}) = \frac{4\hbar bx^2e^{-2x/a}}{ma^3}$
3. $\partial\rho/\partial t = -\partial J/\partial x = -\frac{8\hbar bx}{ma^3}e^{-2x/a}(1-\frac{x}{a})$

Comment: Do $a$ and $b$ have any meaning? Do you want to calculate the probability density of $\Psi(x,t)$ or of $\psi(x)$? Anyway you are right that if you consider a stationary state, the associated probability density is time-independent.

Comment: @Jakob  Sorry I should've been more clear. $a$ and $b$ are just constants, and I want the probability density of $\Psi(x,t)$.

Comment: You could also provide your calculations that show how you arrive that the derivative of $\rho$ is non-zero.

Comment: Is this for a free particle? If not what is the Hamiltonian?

Comment: ...but Ψ is *not* a stationary state, no?

Comment: @CosmasZachos: But if $\Psi(x,t)$ is defined as in the post, then it is a stationary state. However, I think either the definition of $\psi(x)$ or $\Psi(x,t)$ or something else is weird / wrong, because the continuity equation does not hold.

Comment: @Jakob I don't trust his conjectural arbitrary monoenergetic Ψ for a second... Of course it's wrong.  How *could* he possibly get it? He *never* breathed a word about eigenstates!

Comment: I updated my question with the original question I was given and my answers to each part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think about $\psi(x)$ as an initial condition for which the Schrodinger equation will define a time dependence, hence a possibly time dependent $\rho$, whose time dependence is determined by the continuity equation $\partial_x J + \partial_t \rho = 0$. It doesn't matter what the Hamiltonian is for the continuity equation to hold (as long as it's Hermitian).